# One-liner for removing characters from a string

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I have a predefined command `\mycommand` which, for some reason, outputs `{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}`. (Yes, there's a slash after the quotation mark, and there are curly braces.) Could one think of a one-liner or the simplest possible TeX/LaTeX code to remove the quotation marks, and possibly also the curly braces so that what remains is `/home/user/di rect ory//`?

No additional package loading, please.

```
 \def\mycommand{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}
```

EDIT:
The command turned out to be `\def\mycommand{{\string "/home/user/di rect ory/\string "/}}` when the path contained spaces, and `\def\mycommand{{/home/user/directory//}}` otherwise. Still looking for an elegant way of extracting the path.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: This is a string that LyX outputs while compiling the documents, it's called \input@path there and is constructed as follows `os << "\\makeatletter\n"
    << "\\def\\input <at> path{{"
    << docdir << "/}}\n"
    << "\\makeatother\n";`

Comment: So I guess \def\mycommand{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}} would be the definition in my case.

Comment: Any particular reason for wishing to prohibit the use of packages?

Comment: I want to use it in a hack that won't have too much code scattered around. And since I'm only removing the quotation marks, I thought there might be a simple low level solution. Until LyX fixes this as I think it's a bug.

Comment: Since the command happened to have two forms, none of the proposed pattern matching `\def`'s didn't work. I am currently thinking of redefining `\string"` to give zero output, even though this seems like an ugly solution.  Wondering also if changing the catcode for the quote (in the problem originally posted) could somehow help so that the character gets ignored when copying to a new macro.

Answer (score 10):

### Curly braces

An one-liner to remove the curly braces:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\mycommand\mycommand
```

*Explanation:*
`\mycommand` contains `{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}`.
When the `\expandafter` commands have done their job, the following remains:

```
\def\mycommand{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}
```

The curly braces are now used for the definition text.

### Quotes

Another one-liner to remove the quotes:

```
\def\x"#1"{#1}\edef\mycommand{\expandafter\x\mycommand}
```

Result of `\show\mycommand`:

```
> \mycommand=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory//.
```

*Explanation:*
Macro `\x` is defined as macro which expects a delimited argument with the quote as delimiting token. The argument is returned without the quotes.
`\edef` expands the definition text. After the expansion of `\expandafter`:

```
\edef\mycommand{\x"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}
```

After the expansion of `\x`:

```
\edef\mycommand{/home/user/di rect ory//}
```

Then nothing is left for expansion and `\edef` defines the macro like  `\def`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. A LaTeX macro called `\DeleteQuotes` is set up, which removes *all* `"` characters from its argument. No assumption is imposed or required regarding either the location or the number of `"` characters in the argument of `\DeleteQuotes`. In particular, no difficulty arises if the argument of `\DeleteQuotes` contains no `"` characters at all. (Incidentally, as long as the curly braces are balanced in both number and ordering, they are automatically removed by TeX.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{luacode}

%% Lua-side code  
\begin{luacode}
function delete_quotes ( s )
   s = string.gsub ( s, '"', '')
   tex.sprint ( s )
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\DeleteQuotes[1]{\directlua{delete_quotes(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\MyCommand{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}
\DeleteQuotes{\MyCommand}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This assumes the format of the token list is

```
{..."..."...}
```

The `\normalize` macro receives as a mandatory argument the token list to normalize, possibly in “stored” form. The optional argument should be a control sequence that will receive the normalized string as replacement text (no check about it being defined is performed). If no optional argument is given, the mandatory argument should be a control sequence storing the string, which will be redefined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\normalize}{\@dblarg\norm@lize}
\def\norm@lize[#1]#2{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \remove@quotes
  \expandafter
  \@firstofone#2\remove@quotes{#1}%
}
% remove the last #3 in the following if you want to remove
% the tokens after the second quote symbol
\def\remove@quotes#1"#2"#3\remove@quotes#4{\def#4{#1#2#3}}
\makeatother

\def\mycommand{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}

\normalize[\tmp]{\mycommand}\show\tmp

\normalize{\mycommand}\show\mycommand

\normalize[\another]{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}\show\another

\stop
```

Here's the output on the terminal:

```
> \tmp=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory//.
l.18 \normalize[\tmp]{\mycommand}\show\tmp

? 
> \mycommand=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory//.
l.20 \normalize{\mycommand}\show\mycommand

? 
> \another=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory//.
l.22 ...{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}\show\another

?
```

If the code `\def#4{#1#2#3}` is changed to `\def#4{#1#2}`, the tokens after the closing quote are discarded and the output on the terminal is

```
> \tmp=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory/.
l.18 \normalize[\tmp]{\mycommand}\show\tmp

? 
> \mycommand=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory/.
l.20 \normalize{\mycommand}\show\mycommand

? 
> \another=macro:
->/home/user/di rect ory/.
l.22 ...{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}\show\another

?
```

---

Now that the input format seems to be fully known, here's a different solution for both cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\extractrealpath{\@dblarg\extract@real@path}
\def\extract@real@path[#1]#2{%
  % remove the braces and stringify the quotes
  \edef\erp@temp{\expandafter\@firstofone#2}%
  % remove the trailing slash
  \expandafter\erp@remove@slash\erp@temp\@nil
  \erp@remove@quotes
  \let#1\erp@temp
}
\def\erp@remove@slash#1/\@nil{%
  \def\erp@temp{#1}%
}
\begingroup\catcode`\"=12
\gdef\erp@remove@quotes{\expandafter\erp@remove@quotes@aux\erp@temp""\@nil}
\gdef\erp@remove@quotes@aux#1"#2"#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\hfuzz#2\hfuzz
    % no quotes
    \def\erp@temp{#1}%
  \else
    \def\erp@temp{#2}%
  \fi
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\mycommand{{\string "/home/user/di rect ory/\string "/}}
\extractrealpath[\saved]\mycommand

\texttt{\saved}

\def\mycommand{{/home/user/directory//}}
\extractrealpath\mycommand

\texttt{\mycommand}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. Now that I learned about `\show` and tested on the real problem things got even more complicated. What LyX has for \input@path is `macro:->{\string "/home/user/di rect ory/\string "/}` in case the path has spaces in it, and `macro:->{/home/user/directory//}` otherwise. Your thoughts?  @HeikoOberdiek

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Just do `\edef\input@path{\input@path}`.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip If you need to distinguish two cases as described in your comment then you can do it by one-line code: `\bgroup \def\string#1{}\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\input@path\input@path\egroup`.

Comment: @wipet Well, not `\def\string` …

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Added new code

Comment: @egreg Just curious again: if catcode 9 means "ignored; characters of this category are removed from the input", could changing the catcode of the quotes to 9 help remove them in any way? How can catcode 9 be used in general?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip In your case the quotes are already part of the replacement text, so they can't be assigned a new category code (unless you're willing to use `\scantokens`).

Answer (score 1):

First time I play with this kind of things, so probably it's not right. I let everyone correct this answer if he wants.

A four liner.

It's a completely expandable solution, and the `\edef` part is there to show two things: first, that it's completely expandable, and second, so that the `\detokenize` shows that the `{` and `}` *are not in the result*.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\def\endremovequotes{\endremovequotes}
\def\removequotes#1{\expandafter\doremovequotes#1"\endremovequotes"}
\def\doremovequotes#1{\dodoremovequotes#1}
\def\dodoremovequotes#1"{\ifx\endremovequotes#1\empty\else#1\expandafter\dodoremovequotes\fi}

\def\tmp{{"/home/user/di rect ory/"/}}

\begin{document}

\removequotes\tmp

\edef\tmp{\removequotes\tmp}
\texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}}

\end{document}
```

---

A three liner :)

```
\def\removequotes#1{\expandafter\doremovequotes#1"\relax}
\def\doremovequotes#1{\dodoremovequotes#1}
\def\dodoremovequotes#1"#2\relax{\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\csname @gobble\expandafter\endcsname\else\csname @firstofone\expandafter\endcsname\fi{#1\dodoremovequotes#2\relax}}
```

---

Old definition

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\removequotes[1]{\expandafter\doremovequotes#1}
\def\doremovequotes#1{\ifquotein{#1}{\removeonequote{#1}}{#1}}
\def\ifquotein#1{\doifquotein#1""\relax}
\def\doifquotein#1"#2"\relax%
  {\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}
\def\removeonequote#1{\doremoveonequote#1\relax}
\def\doremoveonequote#1"#2\relax{\doremovequotes{#1#2}}
\makeatother
```