# remove "" from lyx macro

Tags: lyx, paths, strings

I am using LyX and followed http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex.

I don't want to use an absolute path with `\addbibresource` so I've tried following there example of using the `\input@path` macro. This didn't work: temporarily changing the preamble stuff to

```
\ifcsname input@path\endcsname\else\def\input@path{{./}}\fi

\def\@@setabsolutebibname#1#2{\edef\@@absolutebibname{#1#2}}

\newcommand{\addi}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@@setabsolutebibname\input@path{#1}%
    {\@@absolutebibname}%
}
```

and inserting `\addi{test.bib}` in my document environment, I see the following printout after compiling the document with pdflatex
`"/home/thomas/docs/testlyx/"/test.bib`.

How can I alter the behaviour, such that the path comes without the apostrophes around it and has the trailing slash removed, such that I obtain `/home/thomas/docs/testlyx/test.bib`?

Comment: I asked the same question  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259015/one-liner-for-removing-characters-from-a-string, and updated the LyX wiki page accordingly. It not a perfect fix (\input@path shouldn't be used in this way) but it works.